# Get the frequency of genomic ranges overlaps in R

Tags: r, dataframe, frequency, genomicranges

I used the GenomicRanges R package to find overlaps between two sets of genomic ranges. The output from findOverlaps function gives two information: 1. the row numbers of ranges that overlap form list A 2. the row numbers of ranges that overlap from list B.

I am interested in overlaps from list A, and would like to add a column to list A indicating the number of overlaps for each row.

Here is a reproducible example that you can directly use in R:

```
#Define SetA    
    chrA = c(7,3,22)
    startA = c(127991052,37327681,50117297)
    stopA = c(127991052,37327681,50117297)
    SetA = data.frame(chrA,startA,stopA)

#Define SetB
    chrB = c(1,3,22,22)
    startB = c(105278917,37236502,46384621,49214228)
    stopB = c(105451039,37411958,50796976,50727239)
    SetB = data.frame(chrB,startB,stopB)

#Find Overlaps between SetA and SetB 
    library(GenomicRanges)
    gr0 = with(SetA, GRanges(chrA, IRanges(start=startA, end=stopA)))
    gr1 = with(SetB, GRanges(chrB, IRanges(start=startB, end=stopB)))

    hits = findOverlaps(gr0, gr1)
    hits = data.frame(hits) #the fist col of hits is the row numbers (from SetA) of genomic ranges that overlap with SetB
    mat
```

I want to add a column to SetA indicating the frequency of overlap with SetB for each row. Here is my attempt and the output I need to get:

```
#Calculate frequencies:    
OverlapFreq = data.frame(table(hits$queryHits)) #calculate frequencies for the first col in hits
OverlapFreq

    #expected output:
    SetA$OverlapFreq = c(0,1,2)
    SetA
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer, and it's simply to use countOverlaps function from the same package:

```
OverlapFreq = countOverlaps(gr0,gr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also using the [plyranges](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/plyranges/inst/doc/an-introduction.html) version of the function:

```
    # direct
    gr0$n_overlaps <- count_overlaps(gr0, gr1)

    # dplyr style 
    overlaps <- gr0 %>% mutate(n_overlaps = count_overlaps(., gr1))
```

I also recommend plyranges for join operations.

```
    # return overlapping ranges
    find_overlaps(gr0,gr1)
```